# question environment in other classes except exam class

Tags: exam

I need to have an environment like `\begin{question}` to sort questions as what `\begin{enumerate}` does. I mean something like this:

> Problems:
>
> 1) Prove that ....
>   2) Show that ....
>   3) ...
>   ...

I know this environment works in exam class, but how can I do it in another classes? My document class is `book` and I can't change this class.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: in what way is your required output different from `enumerate`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle has a point, but you may want to consider the `exsheets` package if you want good control over how the questions are presented.  It implements many LaTeX3 ideas, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `xsim`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xsim}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item State the Mean Value Theorem.
    \item Consider the function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

#### `exsheets`

As of May 2017, `exsheets` is officially superseded by `xsim`.  As of June 2019, [`exsheets` is no longer compatible with the current expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469570).  The implementation below is kept for posterity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item State the Mean Value Theorem.
    \item Consider the function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\SetupExSheets{headings=runin,question/name=Problem}
\begin{question}
  blah
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I do not have the means right now to include the second example (after the `\SetupExSheets` command), but it gets closer to what `exam` does by default.

I'll note that the `exsheets` package is *highly* configurable thanks to its LaTeX3 ideas :)