# Issue after TL update 2019-01-10 related exsheets and LaTex3

Tags: latex3, exsheets

Before yesterday TL update my file compiled well. Today I got the error:

> ! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'n' deprecated for base form (LaTeX3)
>   '__exsheets_blank_skip:N'. One should not change an (LaTeX3)
>   argument from type 'N' to type 'n': base form only accepts a (LaTeX3) 
>   single token argument.

It is related to:

```
\usepackage{exsheets}
\DeclareTranslation{Spanish}{exsheets-exercise-name}{Problema}
\SetupExSheets{
  % question numbering: »chapter.question«
  % use `ch.se.qu' for »chapter.section.question«
  counter-format = ch.qu,
  counter-within=chapter,
  %auto-label = true,
  label-format = ch.qu:#1,
  headings-format={\color{problema}\sffamily\scshape\bfseries}
}
```

Maybe it is a temporary package dependency hickupt?

Comment: The package is no longer compatible with the current expl3 and must be adapted. Make a bug report at the issue tracker of the package.

Comment: Thanks for let me know Ulrike-Fischer. Already sent a message to @clemens

Comment: The function should be defined by `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__exsheets_blank_skip:n #1` to begin with. The only place where the `N` version is used should become `\__exsheets_blank_skip:n {\l__exsheets_blank_dim}`.

Comment: @egreg Why shouldn't it use a `V` variant? I always thought it was intended for passing the value of a variable…

Comment: @TeXnician Is there a `V` variant? The error in the package is in doing `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \foo:N {n}`.

Comment: @egreg No, there isn't. I just wondered whether it would be the better course of action to define a `V` variant for `\foo:n`.

Comment: @TeXnician No, after looking at the usage.

Comment: There is already a bug report: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/44/error-latex3-error-variant-form-n but no fix so far.

Comment: @InventorofGod It's entirely down to package authors if and when they send updates to CTAN. Asking 'more strongly' here doesn't change that.

Comment: @JosephWright: By the way, poking me by `@InventorofGod` does not work. OK. Thank you. I am letting my bounty attract others to investigate the current status of this issue. :-)

Comment: @TheInventorofGod Oops, missed "the": sorry. I'm not sure what others can actually do here: there is an issue in release code, that release is down to the maintainer ...

Comment: @JosephWright: No problem. :-)

Comment: On my Arch Linux system the file `exsheets.sty` belongs to the package `texlive-latexextra`. I was able to resolve the issue by downgrading the package `texlive-core` to a late 2018 version and all my latex documents compile again. I will wait for an update to one of these packages.

Comment: Note that exsheets is not developed any further. The successor package is called xsim (https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim). Taken from https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/src/master/

Comment: I just sent an update of `exsheets` to CTAN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just edited exsheets.sty, in line 2763, instead

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__exsheets_blank_skip:N #1
```

wrote

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__exsheets_blank_skip:n #1
```

as pointed by @egreg, and line 2794, instead

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__exsheets_blank_skip:N { n }
```

wrote

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__exsheets_blank_skip:n { n , V }
```

as insinuated by @TeXnician.

My document compiles again, don't ask me why!!!

(Made changes in texmf-local)

**EDIT** (Mar 13, 2019, 03:10 UTC-6):

Find my edited file, as described above, in [this GitHub link](https://github.com/mlmateos/exsheets.sty-edited).

Place this file in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/exsheets/` directory.

Update the database using the `texhash` (or `mktexlsr`) application.

Comment: You do not need a `n` variant if the base form is already `n`.

Comment: Please get in touch with the package developer to ensure that his package is not using those deprecated functionality/(mis)features

Comment: Sent two emails to @clemens yesterday, no response! May be he is out on vacation!

Comment: @TheInventorofGod Do you really want to compile your documents? Try my answer, it works!! Maybe we should start looking for an alternative package . . .!

Comment: I did not get notified with your `@TheInventorofGod`. I am looking for the latest info about this issue. Has it been fixed?

Comment: err... so how to I edit exsheets.sty? 
Where do I find this. I've been using laTex for more than 10 years, and I've always left those messy files alone.

Comment: @user177955 As I just saw here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478778/18280, the package `xsim` by the same author,  is the official successor of the `exsheets` package: http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/xsim_manual.pdf . Nevertheless, I'm going to edit my answer and add a link and instructions to my edited `exsheets.sty`, for people (as myself) who use the deprecated `exsheets` package.

Comment: @tatojo, does this mean that `exsheets` will not be "officially" rectified and that the correct way to do this is to directly edit the file `exsheets.sty`? I'm just asking this because it's bad practice to mess with files controlled by the package manager.

Comment: @user177955, at https://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets?lang=en, the author says: "As of May 2017, this pack­age has been su­per­seded by its of­fi­cial suc­ces­sor `xsim`. `exsheets` it­self is now con­sid­ered ob­so­lete, but will stay alive, and will con­tinue to re­ceive bug­fix re­leases. How­ever, new fea­tures will not be added any more."  But the fail now is not a bug but "The package is no longer compatible with the current expl3 and must be adapted."

Comment: @tatojo I'm grateful for your reply. Concretely though (I'm not a software developper, just a mathematician) what does this mean? To me it looks like a couple characters in the source code need to be changed to unbreak `exsheets.sty`. Will this ever be done, or is the only solution to do it manually and keep the modified file in a local directory so it won't get overwritten during routine upgrades? Obviously I will avoid invoking this package in the future (it was actually used in a style file given to me by a colleague.)

Comment: @user177955. nobody but the author knows if he is going to adapt the package to the current `expl3`. You are right, practical way to work with the package, IMHO, is keep the modified file in a local directory. Documents compile well. Then, for new documents, maybe we all should move to `xsim`.

Comment: Good news: `exsheets` package developer @clemens, uploaded last week an update to CTAN, so is back! Some of us better migrated to `xsim`, Changes are here: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/commits/23ec59acf113

Answer (score 0):

Just want to extends the solution. On the line 2755/2756 of the file `exsheets.sty` instead of

`{ \__exsheets_blank_skip:N \l__exsheets_blank_dim }`

I changed it to

`{ \__exsheets_blank_skip:n \l__exsheets_blank_dim }`.

It works well for me when I use `\blank[]{}`