# Pycode code inside exsheet question

Tags: exsheets, pythontex

I want to create a table inside of a exsheets question (or solution) (using data defined in another pycode environment outside of it). But this doesn't work. What did I do wrong and how can I make it work?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}[mySession]
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5,6]
k = len(X)
\end{pycode}

\begin{question}
A question with a table:

% The following code doesn't work

% \begin{pycode}[mySession]
% print(r'''\begin{tabular}{c*{%s}{|c}}''' %k)
% print(r'''$X$''')
% for x in X:
%     print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %x)
% print(r'''\\\hline''')
% print(r'''$Y$''')
% for y in Y:
%     print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %y)
% print(r'''\end{tabular}''')
% \end{pycode}

\end{question}

Table outside of the question environment:

\begin{pycode}[mySession]
print(r'''\begin{tabular}{c*{%s}{|c}}''' %k)
print(r'''$X$''')
for x in X:
    print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %x)
print(r'''\\\hline''')
print(r'''$Y$''')
for y in Y:
    print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %y)
print(r'''\end{tabular}''')
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

If I replace exsheets with xsim it works within an exercise, but it doesn't if I have it both inside the exercise and the solution environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}[mySession]
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5,6]
k = len(X)
\end{pycode}

\begin{exercise}
A exercise with a table:

\begin{pycode}[mySession]
print(r'''\begin{tabular}{c*{%s}{|c}}''' %k)
print(r'''$X$''')
for x in X:
    print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %x)
print(r'''\\\hline''')
print(r'''$Y$''')
for y in Y:
    print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %y)
print(r'''\end{tabular}''')
\end{pycode}

\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
\begin{pycode}[mySession]
print(r'''\begin{tabular}{c*{%s}{|c}}''' %k)
print(r'''$X$''')
for x in X:
    print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %x)
print(r'''\\\hline''')
print(r'''$Y$''')
for y in Y:
    print(r'''& \num{%s}''' %y)
print(r'''\end{tabular}''')
\end{pycode}

\end{solution}

\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `exsheets` package is outdated and has been officially replaced with the package `xsim`.

You will need to replace `\begin{question}` with `\begin{exercise}`

Comment: Thanks, but see my edit.

Comment: The ``\printsolution`` doesn't work and should be fixed one day. It's an error in ``xsim``.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Do you have a link to the bug report?